# Enable server side logging in SignalR

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm trying to debug a SignalR connection issue, and while I know how to enable client side logging, I have no idea how to enable server side logging. It doesn't seem to be logging anything to the console.

I've tried using EnableDetailedErrors = true in my HubConfiguration, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was trying to debug a 500 Internal Server Error response, and couldn't figure out how to enable exception logging. Thanks to David Fowler, the maintainer of SignalR who helped me on IRC, here is how to enable exception reporting:

1. Install Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics via NuGet
2. Add `app.UseErrorPage();` before you're calling `MapHubs()`

Now instead of a 500 error, you'll get a copy of the exception returned.

Comment: Where does it log once you enable that?

Comment: Instead of just failing with an HTTP 500 error, it returns the exception text that caused the error. I imagine that's off by default for security reasons.

Comment: I can't seem to find that UseShowExceptions extension anywhere. Can you please share the code surrounding that line? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you install the Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics package using NuGet? That's the package that contains the extension. There's no other code surrounding that line, you just call `app.UseShowExceptions();` any time before calling `MapHubs();`

Comment: after using app.UseShowExceptions(); is there a place i can place my own code to log the exception on the server side ?